# Copy database from my App "A" to my App "B" on Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11

I have released App "A". Now I prepare to release App "B" that should load copy database from App "A" to enable users continue writing data.

This code from App "A" save db from internal storage to a file on scoped storage:

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "/databasename.db");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/vnd.sqlite3");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);
        if (uri != null) {
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write("This is menu category data.".getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(ActivitySettings.this, "File created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivitySettings.this, "outputStream == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ActivitySettings.this, "uri == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivitySettings.this, "Fail to create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This code from App "B" should upload database file that was saved in App "A":

```
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getStorageDirectory();
            try {
                String currentDBPath = "emulated/0/" + DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/databasename.db";
                String backupDBPath = "/data/com.example.mypackagename/databases/databasename.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_db_loaded_succesfully, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_db_not_exists, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_not_access, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DBError", "exception", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_error_load_db, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

It's working as well on Android 10 and below but it's not possible due to new access rules of scoped storage Android 11. With **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission it's possible but in my case Google may reject App "B" due to a policy violation.

**SharedUserId** is deprecated

[Sharing files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing) via **FileProvider** carried out by Activity with UI and additional user's operations.

But I need way without any additional operations, just load database with one click from App "B". It's possible on Android 11? Maybe there is an alternative to SharedUserId?

Any help/thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: `FileProvider` does not require an activity.

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage() + FileProvider.

Comment: App A uses a ContentProvider to serve the database-file-.

Comment: @CommonsWare have you code example without actions from App "A"? [Looks like](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing)   **Intent** and **startActivity** from App "A" is necessary

Comment: `FileProvider` gives you a `Uri` to allow other apps to access a particular file. While you need to use a standard IPC mechanism, it does not have to be an activity. For example, you could start a service with an explicit `Intent` or send a explicit `Intent` as a "broadcast". You would still put the `Uri` in the `Intent` and add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to that `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for idea, now trying that way.

Answer (score 0):

The new security requirements are a welcome change from a security standpoint.

The best solution is to send an upgrade to the existing app A to send the data an external endpoint accessible by app B.

Having App A modify App B data without app B's permission IS a violation of security protocols and should NEVER be allowed.

Unless you are the owner of both app A and app B, what you are asking is impossible and should never be allowed to happen.

Comment: Both apps is mine. Now I try send `Uri` from app A `service` and catch it by `broadcastreceiver` in app B. It worked out. But still can't get file from that `Uri`.